# How to bind a grid to a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, grid

I want to create a settings menu that looks similar to VLC's advanced settings menu: Treeview on the left and some kind of control collection on the right. The controls on the right should enable the user to manipulate settings that are relevant to the current selection in the tree view. I thought about creating a grid right of the tree view. Then I have a user control for each view that needs to be displayed in the grid, based on the selection

The item in the treeview has a `UserControl` property that holds a reference to the relevant view. My viewmodel has a SelectedItem property that indicates which item in the tree view is currently selected.

Now I want to bind the content of the grid to the `UserControl` property of my `SelectedItem`. But I cannot figure out how to do that. I would prefer to use a XAML based solution instead of clearing the `Children` property of the grid and adding the user control that I want to display in code each time the `SelectedItem` property changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `ContentControl` instead of `Grid`.

Considering the tree view and the content control are under the same view model: on your view model, add property for selected item (let's call it `VMSelectedItem`) of same type as the items in the tree view.

In XAML of the tree view add

```
SelectedItem="{Binding VMSelectedItem}"
```

In XAML of the content control

```
Content="{Binding VMSelectedItem.UserControl}"
```

Now selection in the tree will update the `VMSelectedItem` property that, in turn, will update the content of the content control.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using DataTemplates that you have declared inside your resouces dictionay. You would be using only one instance of each DataTemplate which leaves nice memory footprints. You wouldnt need to store instance of view inside your viewmodel which is the basic idea of mvvm. The viewmodel would completely just holding data and information how you wish the data to be displayed.

As example you have an enum inside your viewmodel with values person, car, tree. Inside your DataTemplateSelector you will have an if on that enum that returns what the desired DataTemplate.

Basically you would have everything central instead of having everything per each TreeViewItem.